# Allowing the user to select a picture from a list of options in confluence survey macro

Tags: macros, wiki, survey, confluence

I would like to know how I can add pictures/image functionality to the confluence survey macro. I would like the user to select a picture from a list of pictures in response to a question. First I need to find out a way the wiki owner can upload pictures for the users to select one. Secondly allowing the user to select one picture. I am a beginner trying to learn confluence/wiki technology. It would be great if someone could help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with the survey macro. On the once occasion when I needed to have a survey-esque function on confluence I just used html and js.

On the subject of attaching images I do have experience though. If you go up to the Edit drop down you'll see a link to Attachments. There you can upload images which will be attached to that page.

You might want to look into whether the survey macro has the ability to work in conjunction with the image gallery macro.

Answer (score 0):

Use pictures instead of words in the survey macro option list.

```
{survey:title=MyTitle|choices=!apple.png!,!orange.png!,!banana.png!|changeableVotes=true|showSummary=true|showTopSummary=true|showLast=true|visibleVoters=true}This is a survey{survey}
```

You can also have words and pictures.

```
{survey:title=MyTitle|choices=!apple.png! I like apples,!orange.png! I like oranges,!banana.png! I like bananas|changeableVotes=true|showSummary=true|showTopSummary=true|showLast=true|visibleVoters=true}This is a survey{survey}
```

[image: confluence survey with pictures and words]